# php on GCE, connection to Cloud SQL on same location: Secure enough?

Tags: security, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am running php on Google Compute Engine and a database in Google Cloud SQL. Both are on the same physical location.

While I was able to connect securely with ODBC from my local computer, I did not manage to make an encrypted connection between the server and the database in php because there is a problem in php 5.6 handling the Common Names of a server, so I apparently need to connect in the standard straightforward way:

```
$servername = "ipaddress here";
$username   = "username here";
$password   = "password here";
$database   = "database name here";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

and so on, in unencrypted http.

**My question is:** If server and database are in the same location, is the communication secure enough for handling confidential business data? Maybe it is encrypted anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the traffic between your nodes stays inside the Google network, it should be safe and secure. However, if you're dealing with confidential data I highly recommend to implement your own secure tunnel between the servers and don't rely on the fact that your servers are on the same geolocation.